# How to convert date formatted as string to a number in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I process a report that consists of date fields. There are some instances wherein the date seen in the cell is not a number (how do I know? I use the isnumber() function from excel to check if a date value is really a number).

Using a recorded macro, for all the date columns, I do the text to columns function in excel to make these dates pass the isnumber() validation.

And then I continue further processing using my python sccipt.

But now I need to replicate the text to column action in excel, and imitate this in Python openpyxl.

I naively tried to do the int(cell.value) but this didn't worked.

So to sum up the questions, is there a way in Python to convert a date represented as text, to be changed to a date represented as a number?

Comment: What is the date formatted as? What do you mean when you say a date as text vs a date as a number? Are you comparing something like '2016-10-12' with epoch or are you comparing '2016-10-12' with '30th December, 2017'? Please post examples of the dates you're trying to convert and what you want it converted to.

Comment: 1st question, format of the date is mm/dd/yyyy. 2nd question, on the excel file, when I run a isnumber function on a field it returns false, that's why I said it is not a number.

Comment: Im not converting any format, I just wanted to make the values of the fields, return true when I run a isnumber function on them

Comment: Dates are not considered numbers unless you're representing them as epoch, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to take advantage of the type guessing in openpyxl. If so, open the workbook with `guess_types=True` and see if that helps. NB. this feature is more suited to working with text sources like CSV and is likely to be removed in future releases.